# Saving input type=file in an Iframe when the Parent page is saved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, razor

Im having problem in getting the value of the `input type=file` inside an iframe and pass it in the parent form so when the parent form is saved, the value of the input file is saved asynchronously.

Tried adding `HttpPostedFileBase Image = Request.Files["Image"];` in the controller but the value is always null

heres the Iframe content

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" style="display:none" />
                <input type="button" value="Upload File" id="alterFile" /> <label id="filename"></label>

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

but everytime I submitted it, the value of the field is null, Is there a way to get the Iframe content and save it in the parent form ? Thanks

Comment: Are you having problems accessing this in .Net or in Javascript?

Comment: @DanielLane i tried the .net approach but if theres an easier workaround with the use of javascript , im glad to try and make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have a File input and a Button.

I presume you wish to keep the input with type 'file' hidden on the UI and simply provide a button that says 'Upload File'.

To do this with javascript, you would do something like the following:

```js
var alterFile = document.getElementById('alterFile');
var fileInput = document.getElementById('Image');
var fileValue = document.getElementById('fileValue');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  fileValue.textContent = fileInput.value; 
});

alterFile.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fileInput.click();
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" style="display:none" />
<input type="button" value="Upload File" id="alterFile" /> <label id="filename"></label>
<label id="fileValue">Dummy Value</label>
```

In the change handler you can do as you wish, e.g. pass the value to a top level iframe, etc.